# How to map root endpoint to an ASP.NET Core controller?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I'm designing a REST API with ASP.NET Core and I'd like to handle all requests sent to a root endpoint by a dedicated controller.  Due to how to service implementing the API will be deployed, requests to the root endpoint will be routed to the server's root endpoint (i.e., https://localhost/)

AFAICT, Microsoft's tutorials on [how to create web apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) only cover the usecase where the API has no root endpoint, and all resources are neatly represented by a single controller which shares the same name as the route. In this scenario, routing is handled in a developer-friendly way by annotating the controller class with `[Route("api/[controller]")]`, which creates a route sharing the controller class name. However, root endpoints don't have a name, thus it misses the critical design requirement to comply this strategy.

So far I've been using a class named `HomeController` which is decorated with `[Route("")]`, which I'm not convinced is the best design approach.

So, does anyone know what's the best strategy to map an API's root endpoint to a controller in a ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: Well, you don't *need* to use `HomeController`, but you do need `[Route("")]` on whatever controller you want to be your base. That's how the routing framework knows where to route requests, so it's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was setting [Route("/")] on the endpoint as the controller is set to [Route("api/[controller]")]